# If statement with multiplication

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using this formula.

```
=IF(OR($U2>EOMONTH(AF$1,0),$V2<AF$1),“”,$AE2*(MIN(EOMONTH(AF$1,0),$V2)-MAX(AF$1,$U2)+1)/IF(MOD(YEAR($AF$1),4)=0,366,365))
```

I need to make this formula multiply by whatever is in cell C3 if the value returned is greater than 0. I tried the product function but I am having trouble with placing it into the formula. I keep getting the error

> #Value

Answer (score 0):

You could try placing your whole formula in a MAX function:

```
=MAX(your_formula,0)*C3
```

If you are looking for a different solution, it would be very helpful to have some more information or a data example.